# NSFetchedResultsController Help

Tags: objective-c

My table view is showing nothing (even though there is data), and when I switch back to it from a tab bar I get an error:

2011-06-28 11:25:20.043 Paparazzi[7773:207] -[__NSCFArray sections]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x592d2d0
2011-06-28 11:25:20.048 Paparazzi[7773:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray sections]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x592d2d0'

What am I doing wrong?

You can get the full code at:

https://github.com/blasto333/Paparazzi

Header

```
@interface PersonListViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchResultsController;
}

@end
```

Implementation

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    fetchResultsController = [[FlickrFetcher sharedInstance] fetchedResultsControllerForEntity:@"Person" withPredicate:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[fetchResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    Person *person = [fetchResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.textLabel setText:person.name];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retain the fetchResultsController because it's being released as soon as it is created. The method `fetchedResultsControllerForEntity:withPredicate` returns an autoreleased object. Change the line to read:

```
fetchResultsController = [[[FlickrFetcher sharedInstance] fetchedResultsControllerForEntity:@"Person" withPredicate:nil] retain];
```

Intense memory management on iOS and Mac OS is going to be a thing of the past soon enough though. If you're a paying ADC member, go check out some of the beta releases of Xcode and test drive the automatic reference counting stuff. I've been using it for a few weeks and it's been great.

EDIT: You're not getting any rows to show up because your fetchResultsController doesn't have any data in it. The method `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` is returning zero, so none of your other methods for the TableViewDataSource protocol are even being called.

Comment: I've been using Garbage Collection since Snow Leopard - so it is already a thing of the past for Mac OS developers.

Comment: True, but for iOS, garbage collection isn't an option and ARC is really the best answer. Even Mac OS apps would perform better without autorelease pools (ie. garbage collection). I see no reason not to convert all iOS / Mac OS apps to ARC.

Comment: There is data in my database (temp.db), is there a reason why fetchResultsController doesn't have any data in it?

Comment: Neither do I. I'm just saying that you don't have to do any memory management on the desktop already. Also - Garbage collection isn't autorelease pools.

Comment: If you use `fetchManagedObjectsForEntity:withPredicate:` instead, and store the results in an instance variable (I called mine "people"). I was able to get them to show up. http://cl.ly/2h2Y1N2g1c3s2z2i2v3M I don't know the specifics of NSFetchedResultsController but you must be missing some sort of implementation detail. Either read the docs here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html or just call `fetchManagedObjectsForEntity:withPredicate:` in `viewWillAppear:` so that the data is always up to date.